# mysql character set encoding in older version

Tags: mysql, sql

I am currently trying to run query on old mysql database version 4.x.xx 
as

```
select "something"
INTO OUTFILE '/var/migration/xxx.tsv'
CHARACTER SET utf8
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

but I think UTF8 encoding is not supported. can anyone suggest the way in which i can run this query and get data in utf8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MYSQL 4.1 documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) UTF8 is supported. Try this.

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
$sql = 'SELECT `something`
        INTO OUTFILE '/var/migration/xxx.tsv'
        FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '"' TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '"'
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'';
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: actually I got this thing working as CONVERT( column_name using utf8) with each column.